# MonoDevelop CS0103 MonoBehaviour not recognised

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, namespaces, monodevelop, assemblies

I am working on a Unity 3D project with some friends and I recently started having some issues in monodevelop. Most things, like MonoBehaviour, Vector3 etc... are not recognised anymore. Yet, UnityEngine still is... Which is why this question differs from most of the ones I have read.

[image]

I tried many things:

- starting by reverting to older commits.
- I also asked my friends and its working fine for them.
- I don't get any compiling errors in Unity and I can build and run the game fine.
- I tried removing all the files except the gitignore, Asset and ProjectSetting folders from my project directory and synchronising the C# project again in Unity to regenerate all the csproj and solution files.
- And finally, all my other game projects run just fine, monobehaviours and all other UnityEngine dependencies are all recognised without any problems. Even projects anterior to the one that bugs.

When I open the solution in MonoDevelop I don't get any specific warnings or errors. Except when re-building the solution manually in MonoDevelop. Then I get the following error:

That `Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.csproj` cannot be found (MSB4025)in the project directory.

Which is true, I only have a Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.unityproj.

Any help would be most welcome as I really don't know what to do.

Comment: I will recommend VisualStudio to develop Unity, there is a Mac edition of  VS too.

Comment: have you tried re-importing all assets?

Comment: No I haven't. That sounds a bit excessive though ??